# how to solve $rem(8^{5}+9^{5},17)$ & $rem(3^{8}-4^{8},10)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to solve $rem(8^{5}+9^{5},17)$ &  $rem(3^{8}-4^{8},10)$ but don't know how to start with

Comment: Hints:  (1) Note that $9\equiv -8\pmod{17}$. (2) Note that $3^8\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and $4^8\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.

Comment: There are also good ways that involve somewhat more calculation, but are accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to address the first problem: Observe that

$$
8^5+9^5 = (8+9)(8^4-8^3\cdot9+8^2\cdot9^2-8\cdot9^3+9^4)
$$

and the right side is divisible by $8+9$, of course!

Another way: Follow André Nicolas's hint and note that

$$
8^5+9^5 \equiv 8^5+(-8)^5 = 8^5-8^5 = 0
$$

modulo $17$.

One way to address the second problem:  The last digits of $3^k$ run $3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 1, \ldots$ and the last digits of $4^k$ run $4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, \ldots$.  Taking the difference modulo $10$ amounts to subtracting the last digits (and adding $10$ as necessary).

Another way: Observe that

$$
3^8-4^8 = (3^4+4^4)(3^2+4^2)(3+4)(3-4)
$$

Of those terms, the second is an odd multiple of $5$, and the rest are all odd, so $\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one:

For $17$, use *Little Fermat* first: $8^5=2^{15}\equiv2^{-1}\mod17$. So you have to find the inverse of $2$ modulo $17$.

Note that, as $2^{16}\equiv 1$,  we have a chance $2^4=\pm 1$. Indeed $2^4=16\equiv -1$. So $\;-2^4=(-2^3)2=1$, which  proves 
$$2^{-1}\equiv -8=9\mod 17.$$

On the other hand, $9^5=3^{10}$. Also, $3^4=81\equiv -4\mod17$, so that $3^8\equiv (-4)^2=16\equiv -1\mod 17$, and finally 
$$3^10\equiv -3^2=-9.$$
Thus $\;8^5+9^5\equiv 9-9=0\mod17.$

*Congruence modulo 10:*

It is easy to check $4^k\equiv\begin{cases}4\mod 10 &\text{if }k\text{ is odd},\\ 6\mod10 &\text{if }k\text{ is even}.\end{cases}$

On the other hand, $\varphi(10)=4$, and $3$ is coprime to $10$, so by *Euler's theorem*, $3^4\equiv 1$, hence $3^8\equiv 1\mod10$.

Thus, $\;3^8-4^8\equiv 5\mod10$.

Comment: Probably need some mathjax work on this one...

Comment: @Brian Tung: A single little `$` was missing… and I didn't reread what I wrote.

Comment: Weird—what a big difference that made!